# pyspark cache does not seem to speed up

Tags: apache-spark, caching, pyspark

Here I am using pyspark to do a simple wordcount, I used the cache method, but does not seem to speed up the second time I run the code:

```
from pyspark import SparkContext
from time import time
if __name__=='__main__':
    sc=SparkContext()
    rdd=sc.textFile("shakespear.txt")
    rdd.cache()
    t1=time()
    rdd.flatMap(lambda r:r.split(" "))\
       .map(lambda w:(w,1))\
       .reduceByKey(lambda x,y:x+y)\
       .collect()
    t2=time()
    print t2-t1
    t3=time()
    rdd.flatMap(lambda r:r.split(" "))\
       .map(lambda w:(w,1))\
       .reduceByKey(lambda x,y:x+y)\
       .collect()
    t4=time()
    print t4-t3
```

Then the result is :

```
3.87242698669
2.49692296982
```

If I comment out the rdd.cache(), the result is:

```
3.58677482605
2.52048921585
```

In reading the spark documentation, I am told that cache would speed up the process a lot right? But here it is not doing much of a difference, could anyone give me a hint on this particular issue?  A general introduction to how spark cache works would be great! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

First of all, calling `cache` does not compute anything. It only specifies that *when* an RDD is computed, the results are cached. Computation of an RDD is only triggered by actions such as `collect`.

However, caching can only be used if the same reference to the RDD is used on the second access. For example, here's a version of your program above where the second computation will actually make use of the cache:

```
from pyspark import SparkContext
from time import time
if __name__=='__main__':
    sc=SparkContext()
    rdd=sc.textFile("shakespear.txt")
    rdd.cache()
    t1=time()
    rdd2 = rdd.flatMap(lambda r:r.split(" "))\
              .map(lambda w:(w,1))\
              .reduceByKey(lambda x,y:x+y)\
    rdd2.collect()
    t2=time()
    print t2-t1
    t3=time()
    rdd2.collect()
    t4=time()
    print t4-t3
```

Note that I created a new variable named `rdd2` which defines the transformations that you want to recompute.

Answer (score -1):

That text file is probably small enough that Spark implicitly caches it during the session, so there isn't much difference between two runs and also why the second call to the rdd is slightly faster in both runs regardless.